# Get last date of year java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I can see Java 8 new Date Time API has many class  LocalDateTime,  LocalDate, LocalTime.
I can get first date of year something like:

```
LocalDateTime first = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().getYear(), 1, 1, 0, 0);
```

How to get last date of year in Java 8 new Date Time API ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will always be December 31st (`LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().getYear(), 12, 31, 0, 0);`)

Comment: Of course @MatteoNNZ is absolutely correct. What's the need of finding the last or first date of the year? They are fixed. Do you mean the name of the day (like Sunday, Monday...)??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastDayOfYear()) with [`LocalDate#with`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-12-31
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/N4QJ73)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68558670/642706) is correct.

Another way to do the same is use of [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) and [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html) classes.

We know the last day of every year is December 31.

```
MonthDay december31 = MonthDay.of( Month.DECEMBER , 31 ) ;
```

Apply that month-day (`MonthDay`) to a year (`Year`) to determine a date (`LocalDate`).

```
Year currentYear = Year.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;
LocalDate lastDateOfCurrentYear = currentYear.atMonthDay( december31 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research and exercise i post some method i have tested

```
ZonedDateTime lastDateOfYear = LocalDate.now()
        .withYear(year)
        .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear())
        .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());

ZonedDateTime firstDateOfMonth = LocalDate.now()
        .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())
        .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

with LocalDate and LocalDateTime

```
public static LocalDate getFirstDayOfMonth(LocalDate date) {
    LocalDate firstDayOfMonth = date.withDayOfMonth(1).atTime(0, 0, 0).toLocalDate();
    return firstDayOfMonth;
}


public static LocalDateTime getFirstDayOfMonth(LocalDateTime date) {
    LocalDateTime firstDayOfMonth = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
    return firstDayOfMonth;
}

public static LocalDate getFirstDayOfYear(LocalDate date) {
    return date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear());
}

public static LocalDateTime getFirstDayOfYear(LocalDateTime date) {
    return date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear())
        .withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
}


public static LocalDate getLastDayOfYear(LocalDate date) {
    return date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear());
}

public static LocalDateTime getLastDayOfYear(LocalDateTime date) {
    return date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear())
        .withHour(23).withMinute(59).withSecond(59).withNano(999999999);
}

public static LocalDate getLastDayOfMonth(LocalDate date) {
    LocalDate lastDayOfMonth = date.withDayOfMonth(date.lengthOfMonth()).atTime(0, 0, 0).toLocalDate();
    return lastDayOfMonth;
}

public static LocalDateTime getLastDayOfMonth(LocalDateTime date) {

    LocalDateTime lastDayOfMonth = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    return lastDayOfMonth;
}

public static LocalDateTime getLastDateTimeOfMonth(LocalDateTime date) {

    LocalDateTime lastDayOfMonth = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())
        .withHour(23).withMinute(59).withSecond(59).withNano(999999999);
    return lastDayOfMonth;
}
```